# React Flow: is it possible to dynamically modify the curve of an edge?

Tags: css, reactjs, draw, curve, react-flow

I'm developing a component for my React app using Flow React.

I'm looking to be able to dynamically modify the curve of my edge according to the user's wishes.
Here is an illustration to illustrate what I am looking for.

Before drag a marker in the edge:

[image]

Drag and drop it wherever I want.

[image]

I searched in the React Flow docs and Google but couldn't find anything.

I would have thought to find a special type in the edges or a properties allowing to do it:

- https://reactflow.dev/docs/api/edges/edge-types/
- https://reactflow.dev/docs/api/edges/edge-options/

Did I miss it? Or do you have any idea how I could achieve this?

Thanks in advance !

**-----UPDATE-----**

After Steve's answer, I want to create a custom edge. Since I need to use the floating edge in the example, I'm using it as a basis for improvement.

So I've added an EdgeLabelRenderer with an onDrag event on it.
I'd like to change the position of the center of the edge (set a kind of centerX/centerY?), but I can't figure out how to get this data and set it?

Here's my code:

```
const FloatingEdge = ({ id, source, target, markerEnd, style }) => {

const sourceNode = useStore(useCallback((store) => store.nodeInternals.get(source), [source]));
const targetNode = useStore(useCallback((store) => store.nodeInternals.get(target), [target]));

if (!sourceNode || !targetNode) {
  return null;
}

const { sx, sy, tx, ty, sourcePos, targetPos } = getEdgeParams(sourceNode, targetNode);

const [edgePath, labelX, labelY, curvature] = getBezierPath({
  sourceX: sx,
  sourceY: sy,
  sourcePosition: sourcePos,
  targetPosition: targetPos,
  targetX: tx,
  targetY: ty,
});

const onEdgeDrag = (evt, id) => {
    console.log('labelX: ' + labelX);
    console.log('labelY: ' + labelY);
    console.log('curvature: ' +  curvature);
};

return (
    <>
        <path
            id={id}
            className="react-flow__edge-path"
            d={edgePath}
            markerEnd={markerEnd}
            style={style}
        />
        <EdgeLabelRenderer>
            <div
            style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                transform: `translate(-50%, -50%) translate(${labelX}px,${labelY}px)`,
                fontSize: 12,
                // everything inside EdgeLabelRenderer has no pointer events by default
                // if you have an interactive element, set pointer-events: all
                pointerEvents: 'all',
            }}
            className="nodrag nopan"
            >
            <button className="edgebutton" onDrag={(event) => onEdgeDrag(event, id)}>
                .
            </button>
            </div>
        </EdgeLabelRenderer>
    </>
);
```

}

And what it looks like:

[image]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You didn't miss it -- You'd have to create an entirely custom Edge for this.

Comment: Ok thanks Steve for your reply! Do you have any advice? I'm using the floating edge example because that's what I need but I don't understand how I should set the center of the edge?  
I've added an EdgeLabelRenderer with an onDrag event on it, but I can't see what I'm supposed to set on drag? I guess some kind of centerX/centerY of the edge?

Comment: If I were attempting this I would add a `position` property to the `edge` (like they store it on `node`) to store a center point. Create my own SVG `<path>` string, with a quadratic bezier curve, using that stored center point. Then, make the label draggable and store the resulting center `x`/`y` back in `position`. *(You won't be able to use their `getBezierPath()` because it doesn't support the [quadratic] curve that I'm assuming you want, so you'll need to do that math, but you can use some of their helpers eg. `getBezierEdgeCenter()` to generate a reasonable default center point.)*

Comment: Many thanks Steve, I will try to set this up!

Comment: @Fitspade - did you succeed with this? We have been looking for something similar for a long time.

Comment: Yes @Christian, I managed to do something, it's not exactly as I wanted but it works very well.
I'm going to take the time to post an answer here to close this question and help you and other poeple ! But to quickly explain to you first: When I click on the edge, I make the curve point appear as well as 2 lines which connect the source and the target.
And this point of curve is draggable and will therefore move the curvature of the edge.

Comment: @Fitspade - Thank you very much. I look forward to your answer! From the above, it sounds like you essentially created a new node and an "additional" edge to connect. Have a great day, thank you for answering! 

Did you still create a custom edge for this?